# Creating folder based on one file and files in those folders based on another file using AWK

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting, text-processing

I have a fairly complex sub-task of:
**creating folders/directories based on one file** (`PF.csv`) **and creating files based on another file** (`FC.py`) **in those directories.**

**The two input files to be used**

*Contents of the file* `PF.csv`

```
#######Some description#######
,Rbig,Rsmall,Rmiddle,Lupper,Llower,
DP 0,4.590,0.424,3.5,20,20,,,,,
DP 1,2.949,0.192,1.831,8.508,17.3,,,,,
DP 2,3.103,0.812,1.662,11.456,7.666,,,,,
DP 3,2.418,0.058,1.876,6.295,9.032,,,,,
```

*Contents of the file* `FC.py`

```
###############Some description#############
Lorem ipsum
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.set('B2', '=5.0mm')#set Rbig here
Lorem ipsum
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.set('F2', '=9.0mm')#set Llower here
```

**Expected output:**
[image: Expected output]
For each line of PF.csv, a directory and file inside it is to be created, named using the first column DPx (x = 0,1,2,...). Furthermore, the contents of the files are from FC.py, with changing certain lines using values from other columns (described below, how) of PF.csv.

*Contents of the file* `DP0/DP0.py`

```
###############Some description############# 
Lorem ipsum 
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.set('B2', '=4.590mm')#set Rbig here
Lorem ipsum
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.set('F2', '=20mm')#set Llower here
```

*Contents of the file* `DP1/DP1.py`

```
###############Some description############# 
Lorem ipsum 
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.set('B2', '=2.949mm')#set Rbig here
Lorem ipsum
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.set('F2', '=17.3mm')#set Llower here
```

*Contents of the file* `DP2/DP2.py`

```
###############Some description############# 
Lorem ipsum 
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.set('B2', '=3.103mm')#set Rbig here
Lorem ipsum
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.set('F2', '=7.666mm')#set Llower here
```

*Contents of the file* `DP3/DP3.py`

```
###############Some description############# 
Lorem ipsum 
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.set('B2', '=2.412mm')#set Rbig here
Lorem ipsum
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.set('F2', '=9.032mm')#set Llower here
```

**My code**

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = ",";}
 {
  if ($1 ~ "DP")
    {Rbig = $2; Llower = $6;    #values are assigned from each line read from PF.csv
    gsub(" ",""); system("mkdir "$1); filename=$1"/"$1".txt";    #empty space is pruned from first column ('DP x', x=0,1,2,...) and folder with file is created with the name using system() and filename  
    {(getline < "FC.py");    #FC.py is read, processing further FC.py only, taking the folders and values assigned using the previous codes for file PF.csv only.
      {
        if ($0 ~ "#set Rbig here")     #if it finds a line with this, it assigns the value of Rbig, taken from PF.csv just before.
          {gsub("5.0mm",Rbig"mm"); print >> filename;}
        else if ($0 ~ "#set Llower here")    #simlarly assigns Llower like previous two line codes
          {gsub("9.0mm",Ll"mm"); print >> filename;}
        else
          {print >> filename;}
      }; close(filename)
    }
    }
  }
' PF.csv
```

**Output of my code (not desired)**
The folders are created but only the file `DP2/DP2.py` with the line `App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.set('B2', '=3.103mm')#set Rbig here` is created.

I'm sure it's possible but have not succeeded due to lack of understanding. Please explain in your answers where the problem is and how did you overcome it using `AWK`.

> PS: I can only accept answers using only AWK as it's part of a bigger
>   workflow, but feel free to add other solutions, if possible using
>   shell scripts. Also, the script should be called using a shell script or typed directly in terminal in Linux/Mac.

Comment: Could you please do mention the logic of comparing the files here?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** as discussed with OP in chatroom looks like control M characters are present too in OP's Input_file(s) so one could remove them by doing:

```
tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

OR if you have `dos2unix` utility in your box you could run that too to remove control M characters and once they are removed my code will run properly for you.

---

---

So here is my approach in order to solve this problem, I haven't merged checking directory and its creation part with `awk`.

```
cat script.ksh
##First part is doing directory verification here.
while IFS=, read field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 rest
do
  value="${field1/ /}"
  if [[ -n "$value" ]]
  then
      if [[ ! -d "$value" ]]
      then
          mkdir "$value"
      else
          echo "Directory named $value is already existed."
      fi
  else
      echo "first field is empty so, skipping this line..."
  fi
done < "PF.csv"

##This part is responsible for file creation.
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[++count]=$0
  next
}
FNR>1{
  sub(/ +/,"",$1)
  file=$1"/"$1".py"
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    num=split(a[i],array," ")
    if(i==2 || i==4){
      val_sub=i==2?$2:$6
      sub(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+mm/,val_sub"mm",array[2])
      for(k=1;k<=num;k++){
        val=(val?val OFS:"")array[k]
      }
      print val > (file)
      val=""
    }
    else{
      print a[i] > (file)
    }
  }
  print a[i] > (file)
  close(file)
  file=val=""
  delete array
}'  FC.py FS="," PF.csv
```

I have tested it in my TEST environment successfully, please DO NOT run this code directly in PROD, test it a non live environment first.

***Files created successfully after code execution:***

```
cat DP2/DP2.py
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.setAlias('B2', 'Rbig')
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.set('B2', '=3.103mm')#set Rbig here
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.setAlias('F2', 'Llower')
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.set('F2', '=7.666mm')#set Llower here
App.ActiveDocument.recompute()

cat DP0/DP0.py
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.setAlias('B2', 'Rbig')
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.set('B2', '=4.590mm')#set Rbig here
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.setAlias('F2', 'Llower')
App.ActiveDocument.Spreadsheet.set('F2', '=20mm')#set Llower here
App.ActiveDocument.recompute()
```